# How to set discrete values in x-axis in R

Tags: r

When I plot data:

```
plot(c(1.2,4,7),col=2)
```

How do I display my graph so it only shows whole values on the x axis?

Comment: See the examples contained in `?axis` (all the way at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

First turn off the x-axis in your `plot` statement:

```
plot(c(1.2, 4, 7), col=2, xaxt="n")
```

Then add the axis of your choice, for example:

```
axis(1, at=round(x, 0))
```

where `x` is the unrounded values at where you would like tick marks